# TRichEdit color problems

Tags: delphi, trichedit

```
ans:= RichEdit1.Text     
for i:=1 to Length(ans) do
begin
   RichEdit1.SelStart :=  i-1;
   RichEdit1.SelLength:= 1;
   if ans[i] = correct[i] then
      RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed
   else
      RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;
```

If the letter in `ans` matches the letter in the same position as the letter in `correct` string, it is colored red otherwise, it is blue.

My problem is when I type again the whole RichEdit1 text is colored as the same as the first letter (if the first letter of `RichEdit1` is blue then the whole text becomes blue).

By the way, this is not the the actual code I just simplified it because there are mutiple TRichEdits.
The TRichEdits are read-only and I assign the letters by something like `RichEdit1.Text := RichEdit1.Text+Key;`
(doing this because it's a multiple keyboard program and I need to separate user inputs)

**Is this the correct behavior? How can I stop my color changes from overriding the default color?**

update: Solved it... in a sloppy way (applying the default color whenever someone types), but I'm keeping this open in case someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: First, your code doesn't even compile... second, when are you calling this subroutine?  I did a small example based on your code, added corrections and refinements and it is working very good for me.

Comment: RichEdit1..SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;(you've put an extra . between richedit1 and selattributes.color)

Comment: @jachguate: that's not the whole code, just a little snippet btw. I call it onkeypress.

Comment: @omair: Oh, just a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. Gonna go fix it now.

Comment: I'm calling it on the OnChange event.  Not every KeyPress changes the Edit content.  As said, it works, with flickering, but I'm sure it can be optimized to make less changes.  I know no way to prevent the control to repaint on every single attribute change, thinking on something like BeginUpdate/EndUpdate pair.

Comment: @jachguate: I can't change it to OnChange because it cannot get what key is pressed(it's a read only RichEdit, reasons stated in question). I already have a temporary fix but it's really bad programming.

Comment: @Dian, you edited your question after I first read it.  If the richedit is too simplified (no cut/paste, no backspace, etc.), you can just color the new char and not all the richedit.  Anyway your description seems still very incomplete to make a good (or smart) suggestion.

Comment: @jachguate: There's no cut/paste but there is backspace. I do color the new char with the default color (as I stated in the question) but I'm looking for an alternative solution. What else should I include in the question? Other details seem irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already discovered, you have to reset the default color when you are done, eg:

```
ans := RichEdit1.Text;
for i := 1 to Length(ans) do 
begin 
  RichEdit1.SelStart := i-1; 
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 1; 
  if ans[i] = correct[i] then 
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed 
  else 
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;
end;
RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
RichEdit1.SelLength := 0;
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := RichEdit1.Font.Color;
```

There are more efficient ways to handle this than coloring one letter at a time, eg:

```
const
  colors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clRed, clBlue);
var
  ans: string;
  start, len: Integer;
  cur_state: Boolean;

  procedure ColorRange(AStart, ALength: Integer; AColor: TColor);
  begin
    RichEdit1.SelStart := AStart;
    RichEdit1.SelLength := ALength;
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := AColor;
  end;

begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ans := RichEdit1.Text;
    start := 0;
    len := 0;
    cur_start := False;

    for i := 1 to Length(ans) do 
    begin 
      if (ans[i] = correct[i]) = cur_state then
        Inc(len)
      else begin
        if len > 0 then
          ColorRange(start, len, colors[cur_state]);
        start := i-1;
        len := 1;
        cur_state := not cur_state;
      end;
    end;
    if len > 0 then
      ColorRange(start, len, colors[cur_state]);
    ColorRange(RichEdit1.GetTextLen, 0, RichEdit1.Font.Color);
  finally
    RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Also, using the Text property to append a single Char is very inefficient.  Use the SelText property instead, eg:

```
RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
RichEdit1.SelLength := 0;
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := ...; // optional
RichEdit1.SelText := Key;
```